# How to compute 'map' in Ruby without using blocks?

Tags: ruby

I know I can do this in Ruby:

```
  ['a', 'b'].map do |s| s.to_sym end
```

and get this:

```
  [:a, :b]
```

I'm looking for a more concise way to do it, without using a block. Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
  ['a', 'b'].map #to_sym
```

Can I do better than with the initial code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read a bit about [Symbol#to_proc](http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html):

```
['a', 'b'].map(&:to_sym)
# or
['a', 'b'].map &:to_sym
# Either will result in [:a, :b]
```

This works if you're using Ruby 1.8.7 or higher, or if you're using Rails - ActiveSupport will add this functionality for you.

Comment: It works on 1.8.7 too. 1.8.7 (main):0 > RUBY_DESCRIPTION 
=> "ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]"
1.8.7 (main):0 > ['a', 'b'].map(&:to_sym)
=> [:a, :b]

Comment: lucapette: Yeah, I did a quick edit to add/fix some information.

Comment: Yep I saw it. You know, with all this implementations out there I'm having issues with remembering stuff. When I read your reply I went to check I remembered it well ;)

Answer (score 6):

`['a', 'b'].map(&:to_sym)` is shorter